# How to count how many words in a file do not appear?

Tags: python

I've got four text files containing words and I'm trying to count the number of words the two files do not have in common (number of words appearing in file A and not in file B).

Let's say that file A.txt contains this: 
`apples
bananas
monkeys
treats
plays
ball
puppy
hurray`

File B.txt contains this: `monkeys like to eat bananas`
File C.txt contains this: `the dog plays with the ball`
File D.txt contains this: `cats like treats`

Files B.txt, C.txt and D.txt are all in a separate folder from file A.txt.

The expected result would be the number of words from A.txt that don't appear in any of the other three files, so `3` (for apples, puppy and hurray).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import glob

f_a = open("folder_1/A.txt")
a = f_a.read().split()

dic = {}

for path in glob.glob("folder_2/*"):
    f_b = open(path)
    b = f_b.read().split()

    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)

    dif = a_set.difference(b_set)

    dic = len(dif)

print(dic)
```

The print result is 7, even when I run it through a `liste.append(len(dif))` kind of situation. I want it to return only the number of words from A.txt that don't appear in ANY of the other three files.

Comment: Could you repeat the process? Set a_set  = dif and then update the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import glob

f_a = open("folder_1/A.txt")
a = f_a.read().split()

# Do this outside the loop, since this set does not change.
a_set = set(a)

b_set = set()
for path in glob.glob("folder_2/*"):
    f_b = open(path)
    b = f_b.read().split()

    # Accumulate a set across ALL files.
    b_set.update(b)

# Set difference between a and all b.
dic = len(a_set.difference(b_set))
print(dic)
```

Comment: You can optimize on this a bit, foregoing the use of `b_set` altogether, by using `a_set.difference_update(b)` instead of `b_set.update(b)`, finally computing the result simply using `dic = len(a_set)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy trying to make it so complicated